# Set width/height percentage from code or use LinearLayout and weight?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

My question is very simple. Which is more efficient: setting a views width's or height's percentage from JAVA code, by getting the phones pixel count and calculating the number of pixels needed for the desired width or height, or put everything in a LinearLayout and set the weight of the view.

NOTE: Sometimes the views need to have margins, which are also specified in percentages.

Comment: LinearLayout and set the weight of the view

Comment: To be very honest, it all depends on what you want to show and how you want to show it. Sometimes using weight is better and sometimes its not.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing it through Linearlayout adding weight to child elements add you can easily and margin to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I would like to know which is more efficient, not easier.

Comment: this is efficient way..according to me

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this code `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` to get the width of your screen and `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels` to get height and divide them in the desired ratio and set it to the view.

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: No, it's not. I know how to get the number of pixels, I just wanted to know which is more efficient. Calculating the percentage in JAVA or using LinearLayouts

Comment: definitely using LinearLayouts with weight

Answer (score 0):

> I think the weight is best for comparative distribution of  views
>   within  `LinearLayout`.

its very flexible to use ..you can use it for the distribution of extra space within child or also create the weight oriented  layout by setting the  views height or width(whichever requried by you) to zero .

Nested weight are bad for performance

Comment: Both of them are very flexible. JAVA code needs more coding, LinearLayout is more simple to write down, but my question was: which is more efficient?